# Why won't git pull update local repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm having some trouble updating my local repository to the current master branch on Github.

`Git remote -v` returns the correct paths for the repository, yet when I perform `git pull` it (falsely) says that everything is up to date. Am I missing a step? I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: what does `git status` print? What makes you think it's not up to date?

Comment: because I'm missing a bunch of recent commits
git status says that it's up to date as well. it doesn't appear to ever have been synced, though, since I first downloaded it

Comment: Which branch did you commit your changes to? Make sure you're running git pull on the same branch.

Comment: Also make sure that your local branch tracks the right remote - for instance, use `git status -sb` for that

Comment: it returned this...Any ideas?
``## master...origin/master``
``?? FETCH_HEAD``

Comment: @pkozelka my git log also returns this(with the last three being in red) `commit 2729f77d1727ab21bdb043866c51f330e5e5833e (HEAD -> master, upstream/master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)`

Lol I know something is wrong but I literally have no idea

Comment: Aren't your commits in upstream/master instead of origin/master?

Comment: Your git log is showing that all of your branches point to the same commit. Can you elaborate on why you believe that `git pull` is lying to you? What, specifically, is missing?

Comment: Yeah that's the issue. Git log makes it appear that everything is there, as with git status -vv showing the most recent commit, but none of my files in the directory are reflecting any changes since i first synced the repo