# git clone won't update even though differences exist between the directory and repository

Tags: git

I have a repository, which I cloned. This worked, and the contents of the repository transferred to my directory. I updated a file in the repository, and deleted the same file from my directory. However, when I write:

```
git pull origin main
# or 
git pull origin master
```

I am told:

```
* branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

I tried to reset the stash, but I'm not really sure what that does.

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers to this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488399/why-wont-git-pull-update-local-repository

Comment: No, that question does not have a correct answer. The comments to the post do not solve the problem.

Comment: Actually, it appears the directory was updated. Strange. It did not return the usual message when it updated.

Comment: all resolved then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but I think you want to have your file back which you deleted locally but not on the repository.

```
git reset --hard origin/main
```

This command resets your local branch and make it exactly as `origin/main`, but keep in mind that it will delete all your staged and unstaged files!

It already says up to-to-date, because your local repository is running the same commit as your online repository (it's up-to-date for git), so git expects that you are going to stage and commit the deleted file.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with the process. What does it mean to be running the same commit? How do I stage and commit the deleted file? From the repository?

Comment: So to update a file on the repository you need to first `git add readme.md` (stage) the file write a commit message `git commit -m "New readme"` (commit) and then `git push` (push) the local readme file to the repository. This will create a new commit on the repository "stack" and both your local and the repository are both on the same HEAD which is `"New readme"`. So if you delete the `readme.md` file now you are still on the same commit so it's up-to-date. I hope that explains it a little bit.